# Hover for specific div

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to website development, but I am an experienced programmer, so I should easily be able to pick up on web development.  So, I ran into something that I need a little bit of insight on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>
#menu:hover .inner {
    opacity: 0.8
}
</style>

<div id="container" style="width:500px">

<div id="header" style="background-color:#ccdbe8;">
<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">title</h1></div>

<div id="menu" class="inner" style="color:white;background-color:#4e81b1;height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">
<b>Menu</b><br>
HTML<br>
CSS<br>
JavaScript</div>

<div id="content" style="color:white;background-color:#1c5d9b;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">
Content goes here</div>

<div id="footer" style="background-color:#ccdbe8;clear:both;text-align:center;">
Copyright ? W3Schools.com</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to get it so when I hover the "menu" specifically, it would make the "menu" background a little bit lighter, hence the opacity.  However, this isn't working, it doesn't even make anything lighter.

If I change:

```
#menu:hover .inner {
    opacity: 0.8
}
```

To:

```
#container:hover .inner {
    opacity: 0.8
}
```

It works, but it works when you hover anywhere on the entire thing, not specifically the "menu".  What do I need to do to make it so when you only hover the "menu" portion, it will lighten the "menu" portion?

Comment: `#menu:hover` is enough :)

Comment: This line `#menu:hover .inner` is targeting to different objects. If you want to get more specific with an id and class selector then do this, `#menu.inner:hover`. When you put a space between those two you are targeting separate objects.

Comment: That was fast, it worked too, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#menu:hover` is what you're after. `#menu:hover .inner`  is looking for an element with the class `inner` that is a descendant of the element with the ID `menu.

```css
#menu:hover {
  opacity: 0.8
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="width:500px">
  <div id="header" style="background-color:#ccdbe8;">

    <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">title</h1>

  </div>
  <div id="menu" class="inner" style="color:white;background-color:#4e81b1;height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">
    <b>Menu</b>

    <br>HTML
    <br>CSS
    <br>JavaScript</div>
  <div id="content" style="color:white;background-color:#1c5d9b;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">Content goes here</div>
  <div id="footer" style="background-color:#ccdbe8;clear:both;text-align:center;">Copyright ? W3Schools.com</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This fiddle I have made will show you how to target objects for a hover state.

```
/* hovers */

.parent:hover { /* no matter where you hover in the parent this will happen */
    background: mediumSeaGreen;
}

.parent:hover .inner { /* if the parent is hovered on then make this change to .inner */
    opacity: 0.6;
}

#menu.alt:hover { /* selecting an object with an id of menu and a class of alt to make these changes */
    background: mediumSlateBlue;
}

.alt:hover { /* basic hover state */
    border-left: 10px solid brown;
}
```

Here is a fiddle to play with, [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NmFk5/1/).